# Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 C# Programmatically Change or Evaluate a resource file Build Action value

Tags: visual-studio-2022, embedded-resource, buildaction

Using C#, is it possible to Programmatically Change or Evaluate a resource file Build Action value?

In regards to evaluation, I mean, is there there a way to programmatically find out the Build Action value at runtime?